# Writing file to a sharepoint 2007 server with node.js

Tags: node.js, file-io, sharepoint-2007, file-manipulation

I know how to write file locally with fs.writeFile(). But how do I write/send a text file to sharepoint folder on a different server via node.js?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I don't know how sharepoint works, but if you want to a simple HTTP upload of a file from your file system, you can simply achieve that by by using module `request`. For instance:

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");    
var req = request.post("http://sharepoint_url", function (err, resp, body) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error!');
      } else {
        console.log('URL: ' + body);
      }
    });
    var form = req.form();
    form.append('file', fs.createReadStream("your_filename_here"));
```